# Vowpal Wabbit: specifying the learning rate schedule

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I'm looking at VW's docs for [update rule options](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Command-line-arguments#update-rule-options), and I'm confused about the equation that specifies the learning rate schedule using the parameters
`initial_t`,
`power_t`,
and `decay_learning_rate`.

Based on the equation below this line in the docs

> specify the learning rate schedule whose generic form

if `initial_t` is equal to zero (which is the setting by default), it seems that the learning rate will always be zero, for all timesteps and epochs. Is this right?

Also, what would happen if both `initial_t` and `power_t` are set to zero? I tried initializing a VW with those settings and it didn't complain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if initial_t is equal to zero (which is the setting by default), it seems that the learning rate will always be zero, for all timesteps and epochs. Is this right?

`initial_t` is set to zero by default. By default the initial learning rate will not use `initial_t` to calculate its value but will start off at its default value, which is `0.5`.

Per the documentation, the flags `adaptive`, `normalized`, and `invariant` are on by default. If any of them is specified, the other flags are turned off. In the case that you turn on the `invariant` flag (so in the case that we are not using normalized or adaptive) the initial learning rate will be calculated using the `initial_t` and `power_t` values, and the default `initial_t` is set to one instead of zero.

If `initial_t` is explicitly set to zero combined with the `invariant` flag being set, then yes, the learning rate will also be zero.

> Also, what would happen if both initial_t and power_t are set to zero? I tried initializing a VW with those settings and it didn't complain.

If the initial learning rate is calculated using `initial_t` and `power_t` and both are explicitly set to zero, c++ should evaluate `powf(0,0)` to `1` resulting in the learning rate set to its default value, which can be specified by `--learning_rate`

If you are running vowpalwabbit via the command line, you should be able to see what these values are set to:

```
Num weight bits = 18
learning rate = 10
initial_t = 1
power_t = 0.5
decay_learning_rate = 1
```

Comment: Interesting, in the [docs](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Command-line-arguments#update-rule-options) it says the default value is 0: `--initial_t arg (=0)         initial t value`. And running VW from python interface prints that initial_t = 0 by default: `from vowpalwabbit import pyvw; pyvw.vw("");` outputs `Num weight bits = 18 ....... initial_t = 0 power_t = 0.5 ....` but it does learn.